# amp-image-lightbox activate by ahref or button

Tags: amp-html

how can I trigger or activate amp-image-lightbox by button or href element
I want to write a paragraph at the end of the sentence. click here to link opens image in lightbox

Comment: You can not use a(href) or button, you can use amp-lightbox and do some css

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the current behavior of `amp-image-lightbox` doesn't allow for this. Users must click on the images. However, I've filed two feature requests based on this question. You can follow the progress/participate in the discussion on GH:

[Add action to open amp-lightbox-gallery](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/25475)

[Ability to open an image in amp-image-lightbox by clicking a different element](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/25474)